# Connection database php5.5

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I want to connect to my database using pdo , but in php version 5.5 and php7 not work.
This is my code,

```
 public static function getInstance() {

    if (!isset(self::$instance)) {
        try {
        //    $charset = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8");
            self::$instance = new PDO(DNS, USER, PASSWORD, array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
           // self::$instance->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
            echo'connexion reussie';
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo "failed to connect : ", $e->getMessage();
            die();
        }
    }

    return self::$instance;
}
```

how I can modify this code to be working with php 5.5 and php 7.

Thanks for helps

Comment: I don't think the api for PDO has changed from 5.5 to 7. What error message are you getting?

Comment: no error message, Blank page and with 500 Internal Server Error. in php 5.4 work great, in php 5.5 or 7 not work

Comment: Check your apache/php logs for the error message.